# Prove there is no "slowest" converging series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to show that for any convergent series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ with $a_n>0$ there exists a sequence $(b_n)$, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = \infty$, such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ converges. Any hints?

Comment: Look at the ratio test. From the limit of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{{a_n}}$ construct a  greater limit < 1 for $\frac{a_{n+1}b_{n+1}}{a_n b_n}$ and from there the sequence $b_n$.

Comment: @aventurin what if the ratio test fails for $\sum a_n$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Define a sequence $(n_k)$ such that for each $k$,
$$
\sum_{n=n_k}^\infty a_n < \frac{1}{4^k}
$$
use these $n_k$ to define a sequence $(b_n)$ in which for all $k$,
$$
b_{n_k} = b_{n_k+1} = \cdots = b_{n_{k+1}- 1}
$$

Comment: When you say $b_{n_{k+1}- 1}$, do you really mean $b_{n_{k+1}}- 1$?

Comment: @TonyK I do not, though I suppose the idea that gets at also works

Comment: Then your answer is rather gnomic. You should perhaps make explicit that $(b_n)$ tends to infinity. (I know this is part of the question, but it's not part of your answer.)

Comment: @TonyK gnomic is a cool word, thanks for that.  I appreciate your objection, but I feel that since the OP is looking for a hint on how to approach the problem, this is an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: There are positive integers $n_1<n_2 < \cdots$ such that

$$\sum_{n=n_k}^{n_{k+1}-1} a_n < \frac{1}{2^k}.$$